# Retrieve a secret in terraform from aws secret manager using workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to retrieve a secret from AWS Secret Manager using the following line of code:

```
"${terraform.workspace}.PROJECT_KEY"   = "${jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.take-sm-store-version.secret_string)["${terraform.workspace}.PROJECT_KEY"]}"
```

When I run `terraform plan` I can see the environment variable is correctly translated:

```
  ~ environment {
      ~ variables = {
            "ENVIRONMENT"          = "test"
          + "test.PROJECT_KEY" = "example_key_test"
```

However, when I run `terraform apply` I'm met with the following error:

```
Error: Error modifying Lambda Function Configuration example-function-test: ValidationException: 
        status code: 400, request id: ae52d9bc-819e-4a45-ba0d-a5b4e4de9516
```

Is there another way I could handle this? I have three workspaces (dev/acc/prod) so I was hoping this way I could have one resource (Lambda function) with the environment variables set based on the current workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables can't contain periods. You can test this locally by running `export foo.bar=baz` in a shell:

```
bash: export: `foo.bar=baz': not a valid identifier
```

The [Lambda API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Environment.html) shows that the allowed characters are `[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_])+`.

Ideally this would have been validated by the `aws_lambda_function` resource itself so this error was displayed at plan or validate time but unfortunately it's missing a `ValidateFunc` helper on this part of the schema.

I've raised [this pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/13890) to add support for plan time validation.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks a lot! That was indeed the issue. Good to know.

Comment: No worries. I've also raised https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/13890 to support plan time validation of that parameter.